# Get day names and change service hour list with DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I created an app for a list of consulting agreements using the DateTimePicker script located at [here](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker)

Until now all goes normal, and now, what i want is how i can retrieve the data of the day name which then change the list of consultation service clock (radiobutton).

example:
Monday to Thursday there are 3 choices:

1. 08 - 10
2. 10 - 12
3. 13 - 15

While Friday:

1. 09 - 10
2. 10-11.30
3. 13.30 - 15

Following an existing script

```
<div id="datedays">
    <div class="controls input-append date form_date" data-date="" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input1" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
        <input class="date" size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
    </div>
    <input name="tanggal" type="hidden" id="dtp_input1" value="" />
    <input name="harinya" type="hidden" id="daynames" value="" />
</div>
<div id="hourpick">
    <input type="radio" name="hours" value="1"> 09.00 - 10.00<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="hours" value="2"> 10.00 - 12.00<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="hours" value="3"> 13.00 - 15.00<br/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.form_date').datetimepicker({
        language:  'id',
        startDate:'<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date .' +2 day'));?>',
        weekStart: 1,
        daysOfWeekDisabled:[0,6],
        todayBtn:  0,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        minView: 2,
        forceParse: 0
    });
</script>
```

Update:

i found on bootstrap-datetimepicker.en.js (which included on DateTimePicker download package) this code

```
;(function($){
    $.fn.datetimepicker.dates['id'] = {
        days: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
        daysShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
        daysMin: ["Sn", "Mn", "Tu", "Wd", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Sn"],
        months: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "Juni", "July", "Augusts", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
        monthsShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
        today: "Today",
        suffix: [],
        meridiem: [],
        weekStart: 1,
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii:ss"
    };
}(jQuery));
```

but i still don't know how to get that days value

Comment: and where is your php script? at least you've tried to solve the problem?

Comment: @katona.abel, on my script above, i use  <?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date .' +2 day'));?>  to set on startDate. so maybe i can get the day names with php code, but i still don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

you could use date formatting to get the day of the week

more info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). look for "w"

```
$dayOfTheWeek = intval(date("w"));

if($dayOfTheWeek >= 1 && $dayOfTheWeek <= 4) {
    //Monday to Thursday
} elseif($dayOfTheWeek <= 5) {
    //Friday
} else {
    //other days
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i still don't know hot to get day names value after date picked. also i have add more details on my question